# Flow Trigger IsChanged or PriorValue

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm trying to use the Flow Trigger for both before/after update.
Question is there any way to get compare the old vs new values in the record?

I review few articles but none of the suggestion works
-Cannot use function: IsChanged
-Tried getPriorValue.fieldName__c, but it show syntax error
-Query the record might worked for before but not for update (haven't try it)

It seems to me unreasonable that trigger tool won't have such option....

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no good way and I guess you are already aware of the workaround. This problem was already posted here: [Trigger flow if a specific field on the updated record changed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301451/trigger-flow-if-a-specific-field-on-the-updated-record-changed)

Comment: for before flows -- see [blog post](https://medium.com/be-a-trailblazer/check-field-value-change-in-before-save-autolaunched-flow-spring-20-ed7feb8b93b9)

Comment: for after flows - see [another blog post](https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2020/10/20/ischanged-and-priorvalue-in-record-triggered-flows/)

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter the same issue. It is counter productive to fire the flow on every update of a record.

I believe a suggestion was to query the record and compare it to the record initiating flow and use a decision element - however this would only work (if it does work) for before triggered flows.

Comment: It is fine to fire the flow on every update, exactly as apex trigger, but in apex trigger we can check if newMap(fieldName) != oldMap(fieldName), and run the actual actions only if specific change was made. Seems it is not available yet in the Trigger Flow

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant by my above comment. Have you tried querying the record and comparing?

Comment: Haven't tried, I assume it will work but issue is that I don't have solution for after flow